# Don't let user clear android notification?

Tags: android, notifications

There is a way that don't let user clear the notification without press button inside her? I already set setAutoCancel(false) and it's ok, but there is a button that clear all notifications and I don't want it clear my notification cause it's important to user and he has to read it and choose an action.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("Sync Failed")
        .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"))
        .addAction(R.drawable.change, "Change Pass", pChangePass)
        .addAction(R.drawable.remove, "Ignore", pIgnore)
        .setAutoCancel(false);


mNotificationManager.notify(accountUnique, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
.setOngoing(true)
```

need to be added also!

Answer (score 1):

For that change your last three lines  code like this..

```
final Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
mNotificationManager.notify(accountUnique, notification);
```